# A quick word of thanks for the WB Community

Tags: discussion

I know this is probably off-topic, but whatever. I had no better place to put this.

Most of the time I'm on the SE network, I just go back and forth between a few sites, reading things that catch my eye. This network is like therapy, helping me to cool down during stressful hours.

However, I have to say something special about this one site.

I recently had a tough moment in my live, with lots of things going wrong at the same time and a bit of my little world crumbling over itself. Life went dark, and for the last few months I lost a few of the most important things (and one person) I had on my life.

However, during this time, I kept coming here. Checking out WB, seeing stuff around. Laughing with some of the most awesome ideas for worlds I had ever seen. Smiling from some witty comments. This site kept my head cool, distracted, and made my life a bit better during those times. For that, I'm extremely grateful.

From the bottom of my heart, a huge Thank You for this community.

Keep on being awesome!

Comment: I can relate to the therapeutic nature of world building, glad the site has been helpful for you :)

Comment: Don't worry, talking about the site is what meta is for..it's on topic :) Beyond that...Monica said it all.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Thales, I'm sorry to hear you've been going through a rough time, and glad that we were able to bring you some cheer while you're doing so.  I hope that things improve for you and that you're able to participate in the ways you enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for the nice words... You guys already do a lot of good stuff (not just for me but for everyone else). Really, WB.SE is one of the shinning stars of the internet thanks to you guys. Keep up the good work and be proud of what you already achieved!